# Let $a_n >0$ and $\lim\inf a_n =0$, show that infinitely many $n$ exist such that $a_n < \min\{a_1,...,a_{n-1}\}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Let $a_n >0$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\inf a_n =0$, show that infinitely many $n$ exist such that $a_n < \min\{a_1,...,a_{n-1}\}$.

I am a little stuck on this question, as I feel that since $\lim\inf a_n$ goes to $0$, then the lower bound is $0$. Thus if there were only finitely many such $n$, say $N$, then the lower bound would never quite go to $0$. My reasoning might be a bit/really off on this. Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: Presumably you meant $a_{n-1}$?

Comment: You need to elaborate your reasoning a little. If there were only finitely many $n$ that satisfy the above inequality what could you conclude?

Comment: Note that $a_n$ has a decreasing subsequence converging to $0$. The result follows.